# Failed to mount component - using vue-airbnb-style-datepicker

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuejs2

Trying [vue-airbnb-style-datepicker](https://mikaeledebro.gitbooks.io/vue-airbnb-style-datepicker/INSTALLATION.html#enable-plugin)

imported in my file.vue:

```
import AirbnbStyleDatepicker from 'vue-airbnb-style-datepicker'
import format from 'date-fns/format'

export default {
  components: {
    AirbnbStyleDatepicker
  }
}
```

[image]

But i’m getting an error: `Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`

Versions in package.json:

```
"date-fns": "^1.29.0",
"vue": "^2.5.2",
"vue-airbnb-style-datepicker": "^1.11.4",
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried importing it in `main.js` and doing `Vue.use(AirbnbStyleDatepicker, {})` as it's mentioned in documentation? You shouldn't have to import it in every component then.

Comment: @dziraf if import in main.js, then i get `'AirbnbStyleDatepicker' is not defined`

Comment: Just tried again `Vue.use(AirbnbStyleDatepicker, datepickerOptions)` and it worked. Previously i have used `Vue.use(Vuex, AirbnbStyleDatepicker, datepickerOptions)` or `Vue.use(Vue, AirbnbStyleDatepicker)` why it didn't work?

Comment: But why would you even pass `Vue` as first argument?

Comment: I thought i could combine multiple plugins by comma :) Put an answer with explanation, please, i'll accept it.

Comment: Nope, the first argument is imported plugin's name and the second one is it's config.

Answer (score 2):

It will work if you follow installation guide and register it globally:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

// import component and stylesheet
import AirbnbStyleDatepicker from 'vue-airbnb-style-datepicker'
import 'vue-airbnb-style-datepicker/dist/styles.css'

// see docs for available options
const datepickerOptions = {}

// make sure we can use it in our components
Vue.use(AirbnbStyleDatepicker, datepickerOptions)
```

https://mikaeledebro.gitbooks.io/vue-airbnb-style-datepicker/INSTALLATION.html#enable-plugin